# CSS rules priority

Tags: css

I have this simple CSS:

```
.cont div {

  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.mark {   /* This get ignored? */

 margin:30px;
}
```

With this markup:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div>a</div>
  <div class="mark">b</div>
</div>
```

I except the div.mark having `margin:30px;` but at least in Chrome this isn't true because the generic rule `.cont div` seems to have a higher priority.

Consider I don't want to use `!important` are there any other way to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xNVRm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your selector more specific by adding the tag name:

```
div.mark {
    margin:30px;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xNVRm/1/**

You could also use `.cont .mark` if you want to avoid using the tag name.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid to use the `important` you need to make your css selector more specific. You can use `.cont div.mark`. It is more specific than div.mark.

Answer (score 2):

The ".cont div" declaration overrides the ".mark" declaration because it's actually more specific. CSS uses a kind of point system to figure out which rules apply. In your case, ".cont div" specifies both a class and an element inside it, whereas ".mark" only specifies a class.

For the exact rules that should be used by all conforming browsers, see this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

In your case you could fix this by using ".cont .mark" in the second declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Specificity is key to how CSS rules are given a pecking order. Try looking at this article from HTML Dog:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

You could use `div.mark` instead, *which means any div that has the class of mark, do this.*

Comment: That is true - but I don't think there is any need to be that specific. .Mark is already just perfect. the .cont div is the problem.

Comment: Or, he could just use the class without the div declaration for the .cont class. The specificity that's throwing everything off is at the parent level (.cont div).

Answer (score 1):

Looking over this again, I see I wasn't understanding what you were trying to do. I think I see now.

You are is saying - ANY div inside of anything with class .cont will have 10px margin. It's more specific then .mark. .mark is 30px - BUT it's a div that is inside of .cont - so it's 10px. It reads right to left - that is a good way to think about it and check specificity.

I have come to think of things with a more object oriented approach. What do you think about this approach?

HTML

```
<div class="container section01">
  <div class="block a">a</div>
  <div class="block b">b</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.container .block {
    /* you can style these site wide */
}

.section01 .block {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.section01 .block:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.section01 .a {
    background-color: red;
}

.section01 .b {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

SASS would make this much easier.

a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/FwQHm/) of this example

a [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/JwxAs) of this on a larger scale

Comment: Also - Margin is a bad example on a white background. There could be margin there for all we know. Test with padding and maybe a background-color. just leave out div from your CSS across the board.

Comment: The question markup was an example. Of course I have more than 2 div inside `.cont` and all div inside .cont needs to have that margin, except the ones .mark

Comment: Yes. It's hard to guess your use case. But what divs? .cont is a container I am guessing: so I woudn't put the margin on those... I would have// .repeated-divs-inside, .cont p, .cont .thing { margin: 10px } and keep the container's styles separate etc.

Comment: div.mark {} answers the question - but It is going to cause you more work in the long run I think.

Comment: .cont div {} is already a div. I would love to know of a case where putting div is useful.

Comment: you don't understand what .cont div {} means. It means all div **inside** .cont needs to have margin:10px. Of course there are many divs inside .cont